# How to know if the IEnumerable is the same collection than other?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have a class with a hashset as collection. Sometimes I pass this hashset as parameter to a method but the parameter is an `IEnumerable`.

In this method, I would like to check if the parameter and the property of the object is the same collection or not, to avoid do anything if the collection is the same.

The class is this:

```
MyClass
{
    HashSet<MyType> MyCollection;

    public void MyMethod(IEnumerable<MyType> param)
    {
       if(this.MyCOllecction != param)
       {
           this.MyCollection.Clear();
           this.MyCollection.AddRange(param);
       }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the if is true, so it process the collection. The problem is that the final result is that `MyCollection` is empty, because first I clear the collection so when the `IEnumerable` parameter try to access to elements of the collection, is empty, so the final result is that `MyCollection` is empty. It should be to add again the elements that `MyCollection` had.

I would like to know how I could know if the `IEnumerable` will access to the `MyCollection` property or to another different collection.

Thanks

Comment: Disregarding the sanity of what you are doing, you could use `SequenceEqual` I guess

Comment: Or, instead of clearing and reloading the HashSet, just create a new one to replace the old one. You gain nothing by reusing the old instance. Why pass a `HashSet` as an `IEnumerable` though? This eliminates the type information you could use to check whether you're dealing with the same instance or not. I suppose you could use pattern matching to handle this

Comment: `You gain nothing by reusing the old instance` We don't know how big the collection is. Imagine that it has several million elements and it's called frequently. Recreating it unnecessarily could introduce quite a large space and time overhead.

Comment: You are not describing your problem properly. Please read [ask] and provide a [mre]. You seem to be claiming that if `params` and `MyCollection` point to the same `HashSet<MyType>` instance, your `if(this.MyCOllecction != param)` doesn't work, and that `this.MyCollection.Clear()` then also clears the `param`?

Comment: You could use `object.Equals()` to solve this - but really, the correct solution is for the CALLER to decide whether its the same thing or not.

Comment: @MatthewWatson clearing it and reloading it would be as expensive as creating a new one from scratch, if the `capacity` is equal to the old one's length.

Comment: The collection is very small, about an avarage of 25 items more or less.

Comment: If the collection is small, then just create a new one each time like Panagiotis suggested.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I meant if it is called with the same collection - in which case an optimisation where it did nothing (which the OP is trying to write) would clearly be more efficient. (This is disregarding the wisdom of implementing it this way, of course.)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía you'll have to explain what the actual problem is. What do you mean `the same` ? Same instance? Same data? With just 25 items it may be more expensive to check for value equality than creating a new HashSet with the `HashSet<T>(IEnumerable<T>) constructor. If the operation is very frequent, you could use `new HashSet<T>(25)` to create an instance with the desired capacity, then insert the items with `AddRange`

Comment: @MatthewWatson this could be handled with pattern matching to detect the actual type, then perform a ReferenceEquals. The question is a bit vague

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OP says `Sometimes I pass this hashset as parameter to a method ` which tells us that they are passing `MyCollection` to `MyMethod()`. You don't need pattern matching to check if something is the same reference - you just need to use `object.Equals()`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía In general it's impossible to solve this because even if you check for reference equality, someone could still pass `MyCollection.Select(item => item)` which would cause the issue you're seeing.

Comment: If you want to compare the elements, then `MyCollection.SequenceEqual(param)`. If you want to compare if they're literally the same instance then `ReferenceEquals(MyCollection, param)`. If you want to replace the collection, then `MyCollection = new HashSet<MyType>(param)` should suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible to reliably optimise this, because there's no way to tell for sure that the collection being passed to the method is the same as the one held by the class.

You might think that you can use `object.Equals()` to check for this, and this will indeed work for *some* cases - but not for all. Consider this code:

```
HashSet<int> hashset = new HashSet<int>();

IEnumerable<int> test1 = hashset;
IEnumerable<int> test2 = hashset;

// Prints "equal"
Console.WriteLine(object.Equals(test1, test2) ? "equal" : "not equal");

test1 = hashset.AsEnumerable();
test2 = hashset.AsEnumerable();

// Prints "equal"
Console.WriteLine(object.Equals(test1, test2) ? "equal" : "not equal");

test1 = hashset;
test2 = hashset.Select(item => item);

// Prints "not equal". Oh dear.
Console.WriteLine(object.Equals(test1, test2) ? "equal" : "not equal");
```

So that shows that it's not possible to optimise it reliably just on the basis of object reference equality.

Furthermore, you state that the number of elements is rather small - so this optimisation is unnecessary.

If you really wanted to optimise this safely you could do something like this:

```
public void MyMethod(IEnumerable<MyType> param)
{
    if (!object.Equals(this.MyCollection, param))
    {
        this.MyCollection = new HashSet<MyType>();
        this.MyCollection.AddRange(param);
    }

    // ...
}
```

But I don't think this optimisation is really necessary, so you could implement this as:

```
public void MyMethod(IEnumerable<MyType> param)
{
    this.MyCollection = new HashSet<MyType>();
    this.MyCollection.AddRange(param);

    // ...
}
```

You would have to use the actual type in your code rather than `HashSet`, which doesn't have an `AddRange()` method. The code in your question is clearly not your actual code...

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't clear - `same` could mean the same instance or containing the same data. The original code wouldn't work anyway, as `HashSet` has no `AddRange`.

**Replace the stored set**

One possible way to handle this would be to use pattern matching to check whether the input is a `HashSet` that's the same instance as the stored one:

```
public void MyMethod(IEnumerable<MyType> param)
{
   if(param is HashSet<MyType> h && h.ReferenceEquals(MyCollection))
   {
       return;
   }
   MyCollection=new HashSet<MyType>(param);
}
```

**Merge the new values**

A `HashSet` doesn't have an `AddRange` so the original code wouldn't work anyway. The equivalent is [UnionWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.unionwith?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_Generic_HashSet_1_UnionWith_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__) which would add *only* new items. This would be faster than using `SequenceEquals` and then adding the new items, as HashSet is optimized for set operations:

```
public void MyMethod(IEnumerable<MyType> param)
{
   if(param is HashSet<MyType> h && h.ReferenceEquals(MyCollection))
   {
       return;
   }
   MyCollection.UnionWith(param);
}
```